# MySql Decimal Issue Output

Tags: mysql, casting, sum, percentage

Evening

I have a sports table, which is ordered by success percentage ((games won + (games drawn/2)/Games Played), I'm after output that if 100% of the games is won, then it reads as 1.000, 75% then .750, 50% as .500 etc (with the leading 0 dropped).

Currently I can get it to display 0.000 to 0.950, and if the team has only played 1 match and won, then the output shows 0.100.

How can I:
a) Get it to show 1 match played/won as 1.000
b) show and other combo as a percentage like .500

Any Ideas?

Thanks

```
SELECT team
     , COUNT(*) as played
     , SUM(win) as wins
     , SUM(loss) as lost
     , SUM(draw) as draws
     , SUM(SelfScore) as ptsfor
     , SUM(OpponentScore) as ptsagainst
     , SUM((win*2 + draw)- loss) as score
     , CAST(SUM(win + (draw/2))/(count(*)) as decimal(3,3)) pctWon
FROM (
      SELECT team
     , SelfScore
     , OpponentScore
     , SelfScore > OpponentScore win
     , SelfScore < OpponentScore loss
     , SelfScore = OpponentScore draw
      FROM (
        SELECT HomeTeam team, HomeScore SelfScore, AwayScore OpponentScore
        FROM Game
        WHERE Season = '2015' and Type = 'League'
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT AwayTeam, AwayScore, HomeScore
        FROM Game
        WHERE Season = '2015' and Type = 'League'
       ) a
) b
GROUP BY team
ORDER BY pctWon DESC, score DESC, ptsagainst DESC, team ASC;
        ");
```

This produces a correct looking table, except the top 2 display PCT incorrect.

```
Team    W   L   T   PF  PA  PCT
T1      1   0   0   54  0   0.100
T2      1   0   0   44  0   0.100
T3      0   1   0   0   54  0.000
T4      0   1   0   0   44  0.000
T5      6   2   2   220 122 0.700
T6      7   3   0   247 139 0.700
T7      6   4   0   191 191 0.600
T8      4   5   1   167 201 0.450
T9      3   6   1   142 202 0.350
T10     2   8   0   193 305 0.200
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally rectified this issue!

The problem seemed to be the COUNT for the games played within the CAST.

Instead of:

```
 , CAST(SUM(win + (draw/2))/(count(*)) as decimal(3,3)) pctWon
```

the following gives the correct output:

```
 , CAST(SUM(win + (draw/2))/SUM(win + loss + draw) as decimal(4,3)) as pctWon
```

Answer (score 0):

`DECIMAL(3,3)` gives you no space to the left of the decimal point.  You need `DECIMAL(4,3)`.

What version of MySQL are you using?  `0.100` sounds like a bug.  But I can't reproduce it on 5.6.12 with

```
mysql> SELECT CAST(((1+0/2)/1) AS DECIMAL(3,3));
+-----------------------------------+
| CAST(((1+0/2)/1) AS DECIMAL(3,3)) |
+-----------------------------------+
|                             0.999 |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Note that (4,3) gives you what you want:

```
mysql> SELECT CAST(((1+0/2)/1) AS DECIMAL(4,3));
+-----------------------------------+
| CAST(((1+0/2)/1) AS DECIMAL(4,3)) |
+-----------------------------------+
|                             1.000 |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks Rick. I'm using up to 5.5.41 on the server currently. Have been racking my brain for far too long over it